Rebuild Visual Studio Git (Azure) connection after moving the repository folder to another PC
I have a Microsoft account and use that as a VS account. I have a repository, ForTest, with which I synchronize my personal code.
One day, I copied the entire repostory folder to another computer and I could still work on it (view history and commit changes). But when I tried to push the code, it asked me to creat a new Git repository. When I try the original name, it prompts A repository with this name already exists.

How do I build the connection to my orignal repository?

If you copied the repo, the remote should exist and maybe you just have to authenticate again. What is the more similar in your screenshot is "Existing remote". Try that.

No, copying a respository folder is not a graceful way. You should push all your changes before cloning the code on the other computure.


Copying and cloning a git repo will give you the exact same files. This is more likely down to authentication (that VS is probably doing when you use the clone option).
